# NoSuchMethodException: com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.interceptor.LoggingInterceptorAspect.aspectOf()

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, java-11, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have a code that uses AspectJ. I use the compile-time weaving mode. During context initialization, I get an error. Although everything worked before that.

- annotation

  ```java
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Target(METHOD)
  @Documented
  public @interface AuditAnnotation {

      public String value() default "";;
  }
  ```
- LoggingInterceptorAspect

  ```java
  @Aspect
  public class LoggingInterceptorAspect {


      private LoggingService loggingService;

      @Autowired
      public LoggingInterceptorAspect(LoggingService loggingService) {
          this.loggingService = loggingService;
      }

      @Pointcut("execution(private * *(..))")
      public void privateMethod() {}

  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.annotation.AuditAnnotation)")
      public void annotatedMethodCustom() {}

      @Before("annotatedMethodCustom() && privateMethod()")
      public void addCommandDetailsToMessage() throws Throwable {

          ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
          String message = String.format("User controller getUsers method called at %s", dateTime);

          System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++");
          loggingService.log(message);
      }
  }
  ```
- LoggingInterceptorConfig (It is the error here.)

  ```java
  @Configuration
  public class LoggingInterceptorConfig {

      @Bean
      public LoggingInterceptorAspect getAutowireCapableLoggingInterceptor() {

          return Aspects.aspectOf(LoggingInterceptorAspect.class);
      }
  }
  ```

Here is an error in this line:

- return Aspects.aspectOf(LoggingInterceptorAspect.class);
- exception

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getAutowireCapableLoggingInterceptor' defined in class path resource [com/aspectj/in/spring/boot/aop/aspect/auditlog/interceptor/config/LoggingInterceptorConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.interceptor.LoggingInterceptorAspect]: Factory method 'getAutowireCapableLoggingInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.interceptor.LoggingInterceptorAspect: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.interceptor.LoggingInterceptorAspect.aspectOf()

- pom.xml

```xml
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aspectj.in.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-in-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aspectj-in-spring-boot</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the help of reflection, all public methods defined in LoggingInterceptorAspect.class. But why is null returned?

Maybe someone has some ideas why initialization is not happening LoggingInterceptorAspect.class

Comment: I do not want to speculate, too many possible root causes. I have an educated guess already, but want to know for sure. If you publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, I can take a look and help you solve your problem. Deal?

Comment: @kriegaex: https://github.com/rommy2015/aspectj-in-spring-boot.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. Having access to it, helped me to easily identify your problems as follows:

- Your dynamic `@annotation()` pointcut is quite broad, targeting all packages. I recommend to additionally add `within()` in order to limit the aspect scope.
- In order to auto-inject the logger into the aspect, you want to use a setter instead of the constructor, because AspectJ aspects are expected to have default constructors.
- Pointcut expression `privateMethod() && publicMethod()` will never match, because a method cannot be public and private at the same time. You want to use `||` instead. Or you can simply omit both pointcuts if you want to match both anyway. Also be careful, because in addition to public and private methods there are protected and package-scoped methods too, which you will be excluding if you are only targeting public and private ones.

Your aspect should look as follows:

```java
package com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.interceptor;

import com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.service.LoggingService;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

@Aspect
public class LoggingInterceptorAspect {
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @Autowired
    public void setLoggingService(LoggingService loggingService) {
        this.loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(private * *(..))")
    public void privateMethod() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.annotation.AuditAnnotation)")
    public void annotatedMethodCustom() {}

    @Pointcut("within(com.aspectj.in.spring.boot..*)")
    public void applicationScoped() {}


    @Before("annotatedMethodCustom() && applicationScoped()")
    //@Before("annotatedMethodCustom() && applicationScoped() && (privateMethod() || publicMethod())")
    public void addCommandDetailsToMessage(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        String message = String.format("User controller getUsers method called at %s", dateTime);
        System.out.println("+++ " + joinPoint);
        loggingService.log(message);
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** I forgot to mention one possible problem in aspects which do not explicitly use `execution()` because they want to match all methods: When using `@annotation()` only, you are targetting both `call()` and `execution()` joinpoints, as you can see in the compiler log:

```
[INFO] Join point 'method-call(java.util.List com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.controller.UserController.getUsersInternal())' in Type 'com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.controller.UserController' (UserController.java:26) advised by before advice from 'com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.interceptor.LoggingInterceptorAspect' (LoggingInterceptorAspect.java:37)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(java.util.List com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.controller.UserController.getUsersInternal())' in Type 'com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.controller.UserController' (UserController.java:32) advised by before advice from 'com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.aop.aspect.auditlog.interceptor.LoggingInterceptorAspect' (LoggingInterceptorAspect.java:37)
CLASSPATH component C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(java.util.List com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.service.impl.DefaultUserService.getMockUsers())' in Type 'com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.service.impl.DefaultUserService' (DefaultUserService.java:34) advised by around advice from 'org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect' (spring-aspects-5.3.9.jar!AbstractCacheAspect.class:64(from AbstractCacheAspect.aj))
```

This also leads to duplicate runtime logging output when omitting the  `&& (privateMethod() || publicMethod())` condition:

```
+++ call(List com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.controller.UserController.getUsersInternal())
2021-09-04 16:11:41.213  INFO 17948 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] sample-spring-aspectj                    : User controller getUsers method called at 2021-09-04T14:11:41.210203700Z
+++ execution(List com.aspectj.in.spring.boot.controller.UserController.getUsersInternal())
```

In order to avoid that, you should add a generic execution pointcut:

```java
@Before("annotatedMethodCustom() && applicationScoped() && execution(* *(..))")
```

Comment: **Update:** I added a paragraph about possible negative side effects of using `@annotation()` without `execution()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptorAspect {
```

With `@Component` you register a bean of type LoggingInterceptorAspect in the application context.

```
    @Bean
    public LoggingInterceptorAspect getAutowireCapableLoggingInterceptor() {
```

Here with `@Bean` you register again another bean of type LoggingInterceptorAspect in the application context

Why register 2 beans of the same type when both are singletons?

Comment: I removed the excess, but it did not fix the problem

Comment: @skyho have you removed the `@bean`?

Comment: it isn`t. I deleted @Component on LoggingIntercepterAspect